# NHibernate use Firebird own generator

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, firebird

Having own generator in Firebird DB called `GEN_PATIENT_ID` I would like to leave the generation of ID on the DB side instead of NHibernate and FluentNHibernate. Following this link I am overriding the default Fluent behavior like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414889/how-do-i-generate-ids-with-nhibernate-and-firebird):

```
public class PatientOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Patient>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Patient> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Cache.ReadOnly().Region("LongTermReadWrite");
            mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("GEN_PATIENT_ID");
            mapping.HasOne(patient => patient.Tag).Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.All();
        }
    }
```

However I still get an error because NHibernate is trying to generate its own:

> {"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -204\r\nTable
>   unknown\r\nHIBERNATE_UNIQUE_KEY\r\nAt line 1, column 42"}

Doublechecked if I am importing the overrides and it should be OK:

`mappings.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();`

the save is pretty much standard:

```
var patient = patientDtoMapper.MapFrom(patientDto);

using (ITransaction t = NHibernateSession.Current.BeginTransaction())
{
    patientRepository.Save(patient);                
    t.Commit();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the NH Firebird implementation to see if it supports sequences?

Comment: yes it does. http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html - cite: `uses a sequence in DB2, PostgreSQL, Oracle or a generator in Firebird. `

Comment: firebird version ? in FB3 there are "hidden generators" as auto-increment columns. Also, can u intercept what SQL query was issued by Hibernate to the SQL engine ?

Comment: Debugging is always about "divide et empera" so split your big complex problem to smaller ones. 1) try to make standard Hibernate XML configuration like in the linked question and check if it does work or not static way. IOW the problem may be in hibernate core itself or in fluent add-on. 2) into `PatientOverride.Override` method add call to `System.log` or `System.WriteLn` or what is there for logging in DotNet. Just check if that method is ever called or never. And when it does - which parameters it gets.

Comment: Also, is there any export subroutine in fluent that can export all your dynamic methods into old-school static XML file ? that way you maybe would be able to compare your dynamic XML config with the static config in the linked Q and see what tags are filled in differently.

Comment: Looks like `hibernate_unique_key` is coming from `TableGenerator` (https://github.com/davidmosborne/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Id/TableGenerator.cs). Are you using this generator somewhere else and the override is not overriding?